# What does 'return *this' actually do?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
Sales_data& Sales_data::combine(const Sales_data &rhs)
{
units_sold += rhs.units_sold; // add the members of rhs into
revenue += rhs.revenue; // the members of ''this'' object
return *this; 
}
```

What does **return *this** do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `return *this` returns the current object (As a reference), which means you can now chain function calls on `Sales_data` if you called `combine` on a previous call. This means that something like this would work:

```
Sales_data t;
t.combine(a).combine(b).combine(c); // Assuming a, b, and c are other Sales_data's
```

This is a very useful technique which allows you to create a [*fluent interface*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) which further allows for you to use things such as the [*named parameter idiom*](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/named-parameter-idiom.html) and is present in a variety of programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

It returns the pointer to current Sales_data object (on which this member function called) with updated values of units_sold and revenue.

I guess by this functionality you are trying to update the values in current sales data by combining another one.

Yes, as @Arnav said, it can be used for chaining as it always returns your object address.

Answer (score 0):

It returns the object - in this case a reference to the one used